# Micronaut 3.9.1 throws StackOverflowError with @Requires(missingBeans=) when default bean has annotations

Tags: micronaut

It seems that the @Requires(missingBeans={}) causes a stack overflow in Micronaut when instantiating the bean if the bean has already been processed by an annotation processor.

To reproduce:

I create a default application with the mn command line and added 3 simple beans

```
public interface ServiceOne {

    void asyncMethod();
}
```

```
@Singleton
@Requires(missingBeans = { ServiceOne.class })
public class ServiceOneImpl implements ServiceOne {

    @Override
    @Async
    public void asyncMethod() {
        System.out.println("Execute async using @Async");
    }
}
```

```
public interface ServiceTwo {

    @NotNull
    String notNullReturn(@NotNull final String input);
}
```

```
@Singleton
@Requires(missingBeans = { ServiceTwo.class })
public class ServiceTwoImpl implements ServiceTwo {

    @Override
    public @NotNull String notNullReturn(@NotNull final String input) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
public interface ServiceThree {

    void doSomethingNoAnnotations();
}
```

```
@Singleton
@Requires(missingBeans = { ServiceThree.class })
public class ServiceThreeImpl implements ServiceThree {

    @Override
    public void doSomethingNoAnnotations() {
        System.out.println("Do something");
    }
}
```

I then created a simple controller

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    private ServiceOne serviceOne;
    private ServiceTwo serviceTwo;
    private ServiceThree serviceThree;

    TestController(final ServiceOne serviceOne) {
        this.serviceOne = serviceOne;
    }

//    TestController(final ServiceTwo serviceTwo) {
//        this.serviceTwo = serviceTwo;
//    }

//    TestController(final ServiceThree serviceThree) {
//        this.serviceThree = serviceThree;
//    }

    @Get("{+path}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.ALL)
    Publisher<HttpResponse<?>> doGet(@NonNull final String path) {
        return Mono.just(HttpResponse.ok());
    }
}
```

Use ./gradlew run to start the app and I get the following exception when I submit a get request

```
14:03:41.950 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] ERROR i.m.http.server.RouteExecutor - Unexpected error occurred: Error instantiating bean of type  [com.test.controller.TestController]
Path Taken: new TestController(ServiceTwo serviceTwo)
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [com.test.controller.TestController]

Path Taken: new TestController(ServiceOne serviceOne)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2367)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
        at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2853)
.......

Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$AbstractStreamBuilderImpl.characteristics(Streams.java:316)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamOpFlag.fromCharacteristics(StreamOpFlag.java:750)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSupport.stream(StreamSupport.java:70)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Stream.of(Stream.java:1398)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
        at io.micronaut.core.annotation.AnnotationValue.lambda$resolveClassValues$5(AnnotationValue.java:1448)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:273)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616)
        at io.micronaut.core.annotation.AnnotationValue.resolveClassValues(AnnotationValue.java:1453)
        at io.micronaut.core.annotation.AnnotationValue.classValues(AnnotationValue.java:593)
        at io.micronaut.context.RequiresCondition.matchesAbsenceOfBeans(RequiresCondition.java:588)
        at io.micronaut.context.RequiresCondition.processPostStartRequirements(RequiresCondition.java:219)
        at io.micronaut.context.RequiresCondition.matches(RequiresCondition.java:111)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanContextConditional.isEnabled(AbstractBeanContextConditional.java:50)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.isEnabled(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:100)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBeanCandidates(DefaultBeanContext.java:2104)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.findBeanCandidates(DefaultApplicationContext.java:260)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBeanCandidates(DefaultBeanContext.java:2047)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.findBeanCandidates(DefaultApplicationContext.java:254)
        at io.micronaut.context.RequiresCondition.matchesAbsenceOfBeans(RequiresCondition.java:597)
        at io.micronaut.context.RequiresCondition.processPostStartRequirements(RequiresCondition.java:219)
        at io.micronaut.context.RequiresCondition.matches(RequiresCondition.java:111)
```

etc.

There is the same problem if I use the constructor for ServiceTwo.

Running with the constructor for ServiceThree works as expected.

If I remove/comment the @Requires annotation then all three constructors work.

My build.gradle is below

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "3.7.5"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.test"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-jackson-databind")
    implementation("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut.reactor:micronaut-reactor")
}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.test.Application")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

graalvmNative.toolchainDetection = false
micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.test.*")
    }
}
```

and the gradle.properties just contains `micronautVersion=3.9.1`

Is there any solution/workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us which is the line which throws the error?

Comment: It is when the TestController is being instantiated/having the dependencies injected So, in the constructor 
  
 ` 
  TestController(final ServiceOne serviceOne) {
        this.serviceOne = serviceOne;
    }`